# More Ruby on Rails test issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am on chapter 9 and it seems that the tests are failing once again. Here is the relevant code:

sessions_helper.rb:

```
    module SessionsHelper

  #logs in the given user
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  #Remember a user in a persistent session
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  def current_user?
    user == current_user
  end

  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  #Forgets a persistent session
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
end
```

Here is users_edit_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersEditTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # test "the truth" do
  #   assert true
  # end

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "successful edit" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_template 'users/edit'
    name = "Foo Bar"
    email = "foo@bar.com"
    patch user_path(@user), user: { name: name,
                                    email: email,
                                    password: "",
                                    password_confirmation: ""}
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    @user.reload
    assert_equal name, @user.name
    assert_equal email, @user.email
  end

  test "unsuccessful edit" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_template 'users/edit'
    patch user_path(@user), user: { name: "",
                                    email: "foo@invalid",
                                    password: "foo",
                                    password_confirmation: "bar"}
    assert_template 'users/edit'
  end
end
```

Here is users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    # debugger
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      #Handle a successful save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      #Handle a successful update.
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    #Before filters

    # Confirms a logged-in user
    def logged_in_user
      flash[:danger] = "Please login to access this page."
      redirect_to login_url
    end

    def correct_user
      @user - User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user
    end
end
```

And lastly here are the errors:

```
1) Failure:
UsersEditTest#test_unsuccessful_edit [/home/robert/sample_app/test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:32]:
expecting <"users/edit"> but rendering with <[]>


  2) Failure:
UsersEditTest#test_successful_edit [/home/robert/sample_app/test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:15]:
expecting <"users/edit"> but rendering with <[]>


  3) Failure:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_update_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user [/home/robert/sample_app/test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:37]:
Failed assertion, no message given.


  4) Failure:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_edit_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user [/home/robert/sample_app/test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:30]:
Failed assertion, no message given.
```

This is annoying cause I don't see anything different from the book and the code that I have (in most parts copied and pasted from the book). In the book it apparently works, but when I run the test I get these four failures.

Comment: Have you tried doing what the tests are trying to do, in your browser?  What happens when you go to "/users/1/edit" ? Do you get the users edit form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, you have a typo in your code.

In your `users_controller.rb`'s `correct_user` method, you have: `@user - User.find(params[:id])`, which should be: `@user = User.find(params[:id])`.

Change that to:

```
   def correct_user
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user
   end
```

See if that fixes your issue.

If not, try adding [these two methods](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_3rd_edition/blob/master/app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb#L52-L61) to your `SessionsHelper` module.

If that also does not fix your issue. I would suggest you to clone the [original working repo from github](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_3rd_edition) and try to figure out what you have missed in your version. I have cloned this github repo and all the tests are passing.

Comment: Neither the change or adding the two methods helped... but the original repo did. I did't know it existed thanks!